# How to add parameters to CoinMarketCap API

Tags: python, discord, client, bots

So, I want to create a program that scans the value of BitCoin and notifies me via WhatsApp message. So I have found an API CoinMarketAPI that provides data for crypto values. This is my code so far:

```
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
parameters = {
  'start':'1',
  'limit':'5000',
  'convert':'USD',
  
}
headers = {
  'Accepts': 'application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'd0023d6f-28c7-4579-81a4-410c973161d9',
}

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

try:
  response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
  data = json.loads(response.text)
  print(data)
except (ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects) as e:
  print(e)
```

How do I add to parameters that I only want the value of a bitcoin, since if i change anything in this code it just does not run? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The url you specified is for all listings. If you only want to track BTC, then add this to a filter in the parameters and use a symbol as filter. Better then would be to use the quotes url not the listings.

```
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'

import requests as re
import json

headers = {
    "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": key,
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

parameters = {
    'symbol': 'BTC'    
}

session = re.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
data = session.get(url, params=parameters)

results = (json.loads(data.text)).get('data')
```

This will give you the content and now you can read out the results by adding the elements:

```
results['BTC']['quote']['USD']['price']
```